# Rails currency exchange gem that works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, currency

Just wondering if anyone has used a currency exchange ruby gem that gets exchange rates from an external api and actually works. I have tried the following gems but have not been able to get any of them to function as described:

goog_currency, yahoo_currency, google_currency, yahoo_finance_currency

One of these uses deprecated code and hence does not work correctly.

I am just trying to display a currency exchange rate in a rails view which has been grabbed from an external api.

I have also considered trying to parse the json from yahoo/google finance urls but this seems much harder to do than it should.

Comment: Try more: http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=currency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I picked `google_currency` from your list as most popular and it has been recently maintained. It worked fine for me, I ran the code from the synopsis without a problem.

If you saw the message:

```
You are using an old or stdlib version of json gem
Please upgrade to the recent version by adding this to your Gemfile:

  gem 'json', '~> 1.7.7'
```

Then you may need to update your copy of `multi_json` to avoid the json deprecation warnings:

```
gem install json
gem install multi_json
```

Which should (at the time of writing) install json 1.8.0 and multi_json 1.7.8. Or of course, if this is for a project, you should be able to pick these versions in your `Gemfile`, provided there is no conflict with other libraries in your project.  The message may of caused you concern, but it is not a problem with `google_currency`.

I didn't notice any conflict or problems with the `google_currency` gem, using either the deprecated JSON modules or the most recent ones. To do something similar to what you want:

```
require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'

bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new
bank.get_rate(:GBP, :USD).to_f
 => 1.5513
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that actually worked, although the documentation for the gem doesn't actually explain your method as the primary exchange method and instead gives you: n = 1.to_money(:USD)
n.exchange_to(:EUR). I also managed to use the simple_currency gem.

Comment: @user2514224: Glad to help. The documentation is quite light for this gem, but you can often find your way around in `irb` and checking what's available on any object with `Thing.methods.sort - Object.methods` (where Thing can be any class name or variable referencing an object, and you want to know what it does) and a little guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your original help! Please see my recent question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918014/ruby-currency-exchange-gems-that-work

Comment: Hi i used same code but we are getting the error: "Money::Bank::GoogleCurrencyFetchError:"

Comment: @kotesh: You may need to ask a separate question about that. In case there was a problem (this answer is 5 years old) I just re-tried the code. Works just fine for me. Likely some issue on your machine. In your question you should show more of the stack trace - include stack trace from gems, most likely problems will be network request errors.