# How to get the exchange currency exchange rate in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency, money-rails

I tried to get the exchange rate like this in my Rails app :

```
1.to_money.exchange_to('USD')
```

(Note : I have set the default currency to my local currency which is `lkr`). This returns 0. Im using the `money-rails` gem.

Comment: isn't 1 lkr == .0074 USD? Are you expecting 1 cent?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow Yes it's .0074. That's exactly what I need. Somehow it's droping the last two digits... I need to add this to a hidden field so I can use this rate using javascript to calculate the USD amount real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found from the link @aurelius have posted. Without using `exchange_to`, there's a direct way to get just the exchange rate. Since I use `google currency` gem and have configured it as the `default_bank` in the initializer, I can get the rate like this :

```
MoneyRails.default_bank.get_rate(:LKR, :USD)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution on the [CurrencyFreaks](https://currencyfreaks.com/documentation.html) API. You can also change the 'base' currency and get the response for the specific currencies. For `base=SEK`, you can get the `SEK` to `USD` exchange rate thru this code:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &base=SEK
    &symbols=USD")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port);
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

I hope, it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162830/rails-currency-exchange-gem-that-works):

```
bank.get_rate(:LKR, :USD).to_f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the link you provided gave the answer but it's not what you have mentioned.